# Mailgun send via HTTP API doesn't seem to send

Tags: mailgun

I am trying to use [Mailgun to send via the HTTP API](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api) as follows:

Python:

```
def send_simple_message(string):
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "my-key"),
        data={"from": "<me@mydomain.com",
              "to": ["to@recipient.com"],
              "subject": "",
              "text": string})
```

My domain is verified using the CNAME records supplied, and I tried sending a couple of test `string`s.

Nothing visible happened, at all, from my Python script - didn't appear in sent items (gmail). So I tried manually via Terminal, and got the response: `<Response [404]>`.

Updating the address to `mydomain.com` (thanks @kwatford) I get `<Response [200]>` (success).

However, this was a test email I sent to myself (on a different address). I have not received the message, and it is not in the sent box of `me@mydomain.com` either. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably need to replace `samples.mailgun.org` in the address with your own domain.

Comment: I was suspicious of that - but if I replace that, how does it 'know' to send it to Mailgun's server?

Comment: Oh.. the CNAME record entry..? D'oh.

Comment: @kwatford It now says it succeeded, but I haven't received it, and it doesn't appear to have sent, either..

Comment: I doubt it would be in your Sent box regardless since (presumably) Mailgun is doing the sending for you. Give it some time, e-mail isn't instant.

Comment: You're correct about the sent box, I didn't realise. (noob when it comes to how network type stuff interacts). It was pretty much instant - but the domain to replace is actually your own instead of `samples.mailgun.org` - it's still after `api.mailgun.net`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @kwatford for identifying the issue, exact solution as follows for anyone else confused by the example:

`https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages` should be replaced by:

`https://api.mailgun.net/v2/yourdomain.com/messages`.

What I initially tried for a `[200]` response was simply `http://mydomain.com` which is **incorrect**.

Further, I was wrong to expect it to appear in sent items, though it does appear (now that I have the correct POST address!) in cp > logs on mailgun.com